# Convert every individual parent directory in a GIT repo into its own repo

Tags: git, svn, split, repository

I have a massive SVN repo with tons of projects in it, each in their own directory.

MyMassiveSVNRepo

- project 1
- project 2
- project 3
- project 4

and so on...

I converted it to a GIT repo but now its just one giant GIT repo.  Is there a script that I can run (or someone can create) that will let me make each parent directory into its own GIT repo? (and hopefully still retain history)

so when the script is done I have one repo for each project in my massive GIT repo and instead I have many smaller Git Repos?  the Repo is far too large (15 gigs) to duplicate 150 times and then delete all the files I don't need from each project...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset -o errexit -v
for project in $@; do 
    mkdir -p ${project}_tmp
    cd ${project}_tmp
    git svn init http://svn.example.com/repository/${project}/trunk/ \
        --no-metadata
    git config svn.authorsfile ../svn_users.txt
    git svn fetch
    find */ -type d -empty | xargs -I{} touch "{}/.gitkeep"
    find */ -type f -name .gitkeep | xargs git add
    git commit -a
    cd ..
    git clone ${project}_tmp ${project}
    rm -fr ${project}_tmp
done
```

Usage:

```
./convert.sh project1 project2 project3
```

Comment: ok thanks.  I see that it has git svn in it.  I have already converted it to a complete GIT repo.  cloned it --bare  (i don't have any trunks or branches, its all in the root of the repo) so basically I want to switch the master repo into many tiny repos..  I found a script called git-subtree - https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree  that I was hoping could do the job...  any ideas?